Is there any way we can set up our own fax server using AWS provider?
I am currently exploring options for establishing a fax server on AWS. The primary solution available, HylaFAX, necessitates the use of T38 fax over IP. However, given that our projected usage approaches 1 million pages per month, the costs associated with T38, approximately $10,000, are prohibitively expensive. Additionally, the pre-configured HylaFAX AMI lacks the flexibility for customization according to our specific requirements.
Given these constraints, I am in search of alternative tools or software that would enable us to construct a proprietary fax server integrated with APIs to connect seamlessly with our application. Alternatively, I am interested in understanding whether it's feasible to develop our own T38 (fax over IP) service using EC2 or if there are any suitable AWS SaaS applications that could meet our needs. Detailed insights on these possibilities would be immensely valuable.
